# Find games on local drive

Tags: windows-10, file-management, gaming

Is there some software that can automatically find games in a drive, and maybe move them together in a single folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software

Comment: This seems unlikely to exist, since the folder(s) software or games might be installed to can vary, making a comprehensive list probably unreasonable.